# How to get the value of the text using CSS or xpath?

Tags: katalon-studio

I need to verify text on a page and instead of giving the actual value of the text, Katalon gives an error with the CSS I used.

Here is the Keyword I created:

```
@Keyword
    def usersText(){

        WebDriver driver = DriverFactory.getWebDriver()

        WebElement su = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("#table-page .ui-title"))

        //String usersText = WebUI.getText(findTestObject('Object Repository/WMS/Page_System Users/h1_System Users'))

        return su
    }
```

The following is the script for calling the keyword:

```
WebUI.click(findTestObject('Object Repository/WMS/Page_Dashboard/img_Developer Options_system_users'))

WebUI.delay(2)

String userText = CustomKeywords.'com.wms.modules.general.ModuleKeywords.usersText'()

if (WebUI.verifyTextPresent(userText, true, FailureHandling.STOP_ON_FAILURE)){
    println('System Users page has the text: '  + userText)
}
```

I get the following error after running the script:

```
2019-09-13 09:53:25.756 INFO  c.k.katalon.core.main.TestCaseExecutor   - --------------------
2019-09-13 09:53:25.765 DEBUG testcase.C16354 - System Users           - 2: click(findTestObject("Object Repository/WMS/Page_Dashboard/img_Developer Options_system_users"))
2019-09-13 09:53:28.151 DEBUG testcase.C16354 - System Users           - 3: delay(2)
2019-09-13 09:53:30.160 DEBUG testcase.C16354 - System Users           - 4: userText = com.wms.modules.general.ModuleKeywords.usersText()
2019-09-13 09:53:30.247 INFO  k.k.c.m.CustomKeywordDelegatingMetaClass - com.wms.modules.general.ModuleKeywords.usersText is PASSED
2019-09-13 09:53:30.248 DEBUG testcase.C16354 - System Users           - 5: if (verifyTextPresent(userText, true, STOP_ON_FAILURE))
2019-09-13 09:53:30.484 DEBUG testcase.C16354 - System Users           - 1: println("System Users page has the text: " + userText)
System Users page has the text: [[CChromeDriver: chrome on XP (0c9a9313aebba81a65bf2ff2f68e5a09)] -> css selector: #table-page .ui-title]
```

It should print "System Users page has the text: System Users", instead of the above with the error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`usersText()` method is returning `su` of type `WebElement`. It should be returning the text of that element.

You should just change the `return su` to

```
return su.getText()
```